# Font size showing the same for different headings

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<h1>The Repository For Your Photos.</h1>
<h2>The Repository For Your Photos.</h2>
<h3>The Repository For Your Photos.</h3>
<h4>The Repository For Your Photos.</h4>
```

CSS reset:

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-family: "Myriad Set Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/h8wcL2cr/2/

Why are they all the same?

Comment: Because `font-size: 100%`

Comment: they're the same because you made all `100%` which is relative to the body font-size of 14px set by jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a CSS Reset stylesheet, and within you have `font-size:100%` applied to all headings from `h1` to `h6` which will reset the `font-size` to the browsers default

So, you have to set again the styles for headings

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-family: "Myriad Set Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}  
h1 {font-size:150%}
h2 {font-size:80%}
h3 {font-size:65%}
h4 {font-size:45%}
```

```html
<h1>The Repository For Your Photos.</h1>
<h2>The Repository For Your Photos.</h2>
<h3>The Repository For Your Photos.</h3>
<h4>The Repository For Your Photos.</h4>
```

Comment: Ok. so basically the default font-size is 14px on the browser and the reset causes all headings to be 14px?

Comment: I mean 16px for default font size

Comment: yes applying `font-size:100%` will reset the font-size to the browsers default

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to include this so as to make it as complete as possible

Answer (score 0):

because you have selected all the heading tags and gave `font-size: 100%` to all of them. That is why it's showing the same font size for different headings.